# Iterate through a string and reverse any word with 5 or more characters - Codewars Kata

Tags: python

```
def spin_words(sentence):
        words = sentence.split(' ')
        newwords = []
        reverse = []
        for word in words:
                if len(word) < 5:
                        newwords.append(word)
                elif len(word) >= 5:
                        newword = list(word)
                        for letter in newword:
                                reverse.insert(0, letter)
                        newwords.append(''.join(reverse))
        return ' '.join(newwords)

print(spin_words('Welcome'))
print(spin_words('to'))
print(spin_words('CodeWars'))
print(spin_words('Hey fellow warriors'))
```

Working on a Codewars kata for python.  Need to take a string and reverse any words that are 5 or more characters long.  This code works for single words, but once more than one word is 5 or more characters, it adds those words together for each following word.  Ex: my 'Hey fellow warriors' comes back as 'Hey wollef sroirrawwollef' .  I am just not sure why is is putting different words together and how to fix it.  As far as I know, the for loop in the elif should close out for each word.  I know it should be simple, just trying to learn what's happening and why.  Thank you!

Comment: You are never clearing reverse, it just gets larger and larger

Comment: Just put `reverse = []` in the first line inside the for loop. So a new, empty `reverse` is generated for each word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simple answer:

You have to clear your reversed word:

```
def spin_words(sentence):
        words = sentence.split(' ')
        newwords = []
        reverse = []
        for word in words:
                if len(word) < 5:
                        newwords.append(word)
                elif len(word) >= 5:
                        newword = list(word)
                        for letter in newword:
                                reverse.insert(0, letter)
                        newwords.append(''.join(reverse))
                        reverse = [] # Clear the list.
        return ' '.join(newwords)

print(spin_words('Welcome'))
print(spin_words('to'))
print(spin_words('CodeWars'))
print(spin_words('Hey fellow warriors'))
```

Output:

```
emocleW
to
sraWedoC
Hey wollef sroirraw
```

## Nicer answer:

After Ignatius Reilly's comment I made my solution a bit more elegant:

```
def spin_words(sentence):
    words = sentence.split(' ')
    newwords = []
    for word in words:
        if len(word) >= 5:
            word = word[::-1]
        newwords.append(word)
    return ' '.join(newwords)
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_howto_reverse_string.asp) is how I reversed the word.

Output is the same.

Comment: This works, but is a bit inelegant: not only you have an extra line, and make an extra assignation for the last word but, more important, you miss encapsulating the procedure for a single word. Can you think of an algorithm that that processes a single word (that could be wrapped in a function) and then use the for loop to apply it to each word?